# Angular 5 - ngFor with pipe and on click event

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor, key-events, pipes-filters

I loop through an array of objects with `*ngFor` and apply a couple of pipes which filter the resulting list.
One of the pipes uses a user input from a search field.
When a user clicks one of the ngFor elements, the object is sent to a function and added to a "selection" array, to be used later.

```
<input type="search" [(ngModel)]="searchInput"> 
<a *ngFor="let item of items | firstFilter | inputFilter:searchInput; let i = index">
 <span (click)="send(item)"> send {{item.name}} </span>
</a>
```

I am trying to replicate the behaviour of a search field (like google) where the first result is highlighted and if the user presses enter while typing, it would trigger the same action as clicking on the result `send(item)`.

[image]

Highlighting is easy enough with ngClass checking if the input is not empty and i === 0.

What I got stuck with is the enter key press event.

- How would I listen to the event in the input field, from inside the ngFor loop, and only for the first result (i===0) ?
- Is there a way to record the list of objects (or at least the first
  one), after the pipes have been applied to the items array?
- How would you suggest to go about this?

Comment: Side note on your code: the Angular team specifically recommend not to use a pipe to filter a list (see [here](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe))

Comment: In terms of solving your actual problem, I would have a look at pre-built components. The angular material library offers an autocomplete element (see [here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/earkdkgoqegp?file=app%2Fautocomplete-auto-active-first-option-example.ts)) with exactly the kind of functionality you are looking for

Comment: Very useful! I assumed I would need to move the 'filter' into the component.

Comment: well if you want to filter the list before displaying it to the user, you can easily do that in your `ts`, so that the autocomplete element only has the items you want the user to see.

Comment: I didn't want to use the Material autocomplete as it didn't offer me the interface I wanted and decided to create my own. I needed a list a user can browse through and also search through.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input 
    type="search" 
    [(ngModel)]="searchInput"
    (keyup.enter)="selectFirstElement()"> 
<a *ngFor="let item of items | firstFilter | inputFilter:searchInput; let i = index">
 <span 
    (click)="send(item)"> send {{item.name}} </span>
</a>
```

Add a method selectFirstElement which will access the first element or the one which is highlighted when the user presses enter.

Comment: What you suggested is exactly what I don't know how to do. How do you access the first element from the component ?

Comment: You should be able to access the first component using item[0]. This is just an array. I updated the code.

Comment: I've tried detecting the keyup.enter from the loop, it doesn't listen to the event in the input field. Also, the component cannot access the internal logic from inside an `*ngFor` loop simply by recalling it's items. It's like trying to call `i` from outside `for(i=0,i<10,i++){...}`. i can call items[0] but it would give me the index of the original array, not the filtered array i used pipes on. I believe I would need to move the whole logic into the ts file.

Comment: Yes, I see the comments under your question - would be better to move the filter logic to the component itself, then you'll have access to all the elements of the list. Then using the first (keyup.enter) you can call a method which has got access to the filtered list, and the first element.